# Legendre equation solution at the regular singular point, infinity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, legendre-polynomials

Consider the Legendre equation,
$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+\alpha (\alpha +1)y=0$$

Let $x=1/t$, then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-t^2\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=t^4\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+2t^3\frac{dy}{dt}$$

The equations becomes (I write $y_t$ to denote a derrivative w.r.t $t$),
$$(1-\frac{1}{t^2})(t^4y_{tt}+2t^3y_t)-2(\frac{1}{t})(-t^2y_t)+\alpha(\alpha+1)y=0$$
or,
$$t^2(t^2-1)y_{tt}-2t^3y_t+\alpha(\alpha+1)y=0$$
We see we have a singular point at $t=0\ (x=\infty)$ since,
$$b_1(t)=t\frac{2t^3}{t^2(t^2-1)}=\frac{2t^2}{(t^2-1)}$$
$$b_2(t)=t^2\frac{\alpha (\alpha+1)}{t^2(t^2-1)}=\frac{\alpha (\alpha+1)}{(t^2-1)}$$
are both analytic around $t=0$. Thus it is a regular singular point. The indicial polynomial is **(I'm not sure if this is correct)**,
$$r(r-1)+b_1(0)r+b_2(0)=0$$
$$r(r-1)+0r-\alpha(\alpha +1)=0$$
which has solutions, $r_1=\alpha+1,\ r_2=-\alpha$.

Now my question is concerning a special case of the Legendre polynomial when $\alpha =1$, or,
$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+2y=0$$
I am asked to find 2 L.I. solutions of the form,
$$\phi(x)=x^{-r}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^{-k}$$
valid for $|x|>1$.

**My attempt**
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^{-k-r}$$
$$\phi'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(-k-r)x^{-k-r-1}$$
$$\phi''(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(-k-r)(-k-r-1)x^{-k-r-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(k+r)(k+r+1)x^{-k-r-2}$$
Plugging this into the equation I get,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(k+r)(k+r+1)x^{-k-r-2}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(k+r)(k+r+1)x^{-k-r}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2c_k(-k-r)x^{-k-r}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2c_kx^{-k-r}=0$$

Doing the change of indecies in the first some for $k\to k-2$ and combining the last 3 sums gives,
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}c_{k-2}(k+r-2)(k+r-1)x^{-k-r}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^{-k-r}[-(k+r)(k+r+1)+2(k+r)+2]=0$$
Taking out the first 2 terms of the last sum gives,
$$ c_0x^{-r}[-r(r+1)+2r+2]+c_1x^{-r-1}[-(r+1)(r+2)+2(r+1)+2]+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}x^{-k-r}\{c_{k-2}[(k+r-2)(k+r-1)]+c_k[-(k+r)(k+r+1)+2(k+r)+2]\}=0$$

If $c_0 \neq 0$ and $c_1 \neq 0$, then we get 2 indicial polynomials for the roots of r,
$$-r(r+1)+2r+2=0$$
and,
$$-(r+1)(r+2)+2(r+1)+2=0$$

which both have different roots, so I'm not sure if I simply made a calculation error somewhere, or if I am missing something.

Furthermore, only the second indicial equation would match up with the one found earlier, with roots $-\alpha$ and $\alpha +1$.

Comment: Here is my answer (since it is too long, i do put in two separate comments):
$y=c_1\left(1+\frac{x^2\left(-α^2-α\right)}{2}+\frac{x^4\left(-α^2-α\right)\left(-α^2-α+6\right)}{24}+\ldots \:+\frac{x^{2n}\left(-α^2-α+6-\left(6\right)\right)\left(-α^2-α+18-\left(12\right)\right)\left(-α^2-α+4n^2+2-6n\right)}{\left(1\right)\left(2\right)\left(3\right)\left(4\right)\ldots \:2n\left(2n-1\right)}+\ldots \:\right)$

Comment: Continued:
$+$
$c_2\left(x+\frac{x^3\left(-α^2-α+2\right)}{6}+\frac{x^5\left(-α^2-α+2\right)\left(-α^2-α+12\right)}{120}+\ldots \:+\frac{x^{2n+1}\left(-α^2-α+11-\left(9\right)\right)\left(-α^2-α+27-\left(15\right)\right)\left(-α^2-α+4n^2-2n\right)}{\left(2\right)\left(3\right)\left(4\right)\left(5\right)\ldots \:2n\left(2n+1\right)}+\ldots \:\right)$